# iPhone 3GS won't let iMessage show my number; only email

Tags: iphone, messages

On my iPhone 3GS, iMessage recently started sending it via email. I've tried everything and I've checked Send & Receive and it won't even let me click on my phone number as an option. It also says "waiting for activation", under the option of turning iMessage on. How do I fix it to where it says my phone number and not my email?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the best solution to these iMessage and Face Time woes is to just turn the service off, then back on again. That causes it to re-activate with Apple's servers, which should register your phone number as a usable iMessage sender.

The "Waiting for Activation" message suggests that this process wasn't completed properly, and/or there's some issue with Apple's servers. Try toggling it, and if it still doesn't work, try it again later, as it may be a server side issue that you need to wait for Apple to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue I had following this method using iTunes:

[Fix for iMessage and FaceTime (YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRNzXReLV44)